# How to make content elements appear / be added on a specific % of a @keyframe animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I've been trying to solve this issue on having my `.content` children appear (either be added or opacity going from 0-100%) as the current animation is going over that element if that makes sense. I tried using `JS AnimationIteration Event listener` but that also didn't work as I require multiple iterations to be made which is not what I'm looking for. Also cannot think of any way to hard code this for examples but I made a basic way of how I want my animation to appear and also the other elements showing before the animation. NOTE: IDK why `height: 100%;` does not cover the entire content height including all the children.

`Informal section below`

Image I have 3 elements that are inside the `.content` div and I have a dropdown menu that animates the background of the `.content` to appear going downwards from `0% {height: 0} -> 100%: {height: 100%}` and as the animation reaches 33% I want 1st child of `.content` to appear while the other 2 are still hidden and wont show until the animation reaches them / goes past them and then the child appears. I want to also make it so that if in the future I add lets say extra 5 elements I don't have to go into the code and adjust the timings and it will automatically know when to start the child animation appearing.

I don't have a clue if this is possible or not, or my imagination is being too much for my skill level. I'm working on a very modular website for my personal projects and this is one of the things I would love to have a part of it. If this is too much I just wont bother with this but would be awesome to see potentially some things that people can help me with to solve this.

**Old Example**

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropbtn i {
  color: red;
  scale: 1.9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .content {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  animation: test 2s ease-in-out;
}

.content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Advanced Animated Dropdown Menu Prototype</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

  <link href='https://unpkg.com/css.gg@2.0.0/icons/css/arrow-down-r.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <i class="gg-arrow-down-r"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updated code**

Possible solution that I managed to get is this using `overflow: auto`

I'm happy with outcome but still would like custom animations on children of the parent and issue of `100% height` still there dont have a clue why.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropbtn i {
  color: red;
  scale: 1.9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .content {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  animation: test 2s ease-in-out;
}

.content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Advanced Animated Dropdown Menu Prototype</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

  <link href='https://unpkg.com/css.gg@2.0.0/icons/css/arrow-down-r.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <i class="gg-arrow-down-r"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`Resources used`

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) as always to understand some animations but W3Schools is sapposably outdated

[Element: animationiteration event(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationiteration_event) For animation events

I also tried `ChatGPT` but I only have access to 3.5 not 4 so it was a waste of time AHAHA like always.

Comment: Could you explain what 'current animation going over that element' means? Thanks. I especially don't understand the 'over' - should that be 'under' (in the z-axis sense)? Also is anything known about the height of the list elements? Are they equal or could they be anything e.g. depending on content?

Comment: @AHaworth  What I mean by `over` is that, I have a background which is `.content` and that is `the height of the content inside the div` and I want so when the background animation reaches a specific point e.g. 1st child of `.content` at which point that specific child will starts its own animation which can either be opacity change or any other animation. Please let me know if I explained that well to you. I have a vision but so hard to explain in words... :(

Comment: I have managed to come up with something that does a certain part of my problem which hides the child elements until background is shown but don't have access to custom animation cues for each child element :( and also this issue with `100%` height also weird as hell had to use hard coded height for the update. Please check on updated section

Comment: So,is one of the issues that you have had to build in/guess at the height?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding what you're trying to ask me with that comment? `one of the issues that you have had to` **build in/guess** `at the height?`. Please mind re-wording that.

Comment: yo've set the height at 100px. How was that arrived at?

Comment: Just guessing for this example there is no specific value to 100px I would love it to be 100% so it becomes responsive with additional child elements, but once I make it 100% it only animates up to 1st child and stops... HONESTLY MIND BLOWN

Comment: The 100% height is 100% of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this issue for over a day I have come up with a solution that doesn't match what I wanted but works as I wanted. (I will try to update my question to match the solution so people who might want this can understand better what I meant). This solution works with any number of children and the width of the dropdown scales with the span / input size as that's the intended use case on my part.

I was having an issue with loading all the code so it might not work all the time so I made this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/DaLegacy/pen/abMYKYX) link to check out the solution if it doesn't work here.

```js
const dropDown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
const content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
const child = document.getElementsByClassName('child')[0];
const numChildren = document.getElementsByClassName('child').length;
var contentHeight;

// On DOMCOntentLoaded Gather information about chidren and the the contentHeight for the dropdown. This can be improved to work with a much better updating time instead of re-loading the page all the time if things change within the variables. (Thing for later)

// Future improvements: Use cookies to store the contentHeight so this doesn't have to be executed every time the page is refreshed. Add if statement if the height is available and return;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) =>{
  content.style.display = 'block';
  contentHeight = child.offsetHeight * numChildren;
  content.style.display = 'none';
});

dropDown.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  content.style.display = 'block';

  var computedHeight = getComputedStyle(content).getPropertyValue('--content-height');
  if (computedHeight == `${contentHeight}px`){
    return;
  }
  content.style.setProperty('--content-height', `${contentHeight}px`);
});

dropDown.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  content.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropbtn i {
  color: red;
  scale: 1.9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  --content-height: 0px;

  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* Only here to make the dropdown appear from the left side instead of the right. */
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .content {
  animation: dropDownUnroll 1s ease-in-out;
}

.content div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content span {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

@keyframes dropDownUnroll {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: var(--content-height);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Advanced Animated Dropdown Menu Prototype</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

  <link href='https://unpkg.com/css.gg@2.0.0/icons/css/arrow-down-r.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <i class="gg-arrow-down-r"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        <span>Item 1: </span>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <span>Item 2: </span>
        <input type="color">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <span>The Width Will scale with the size of the span: </span>
        <input type="range">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we don't know the height of .content and as we can't animate to fit-content height, here's another way of doing similar to the second example given.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Advanced Animated Dropdown Menu Prototype</title>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">-->

  <link href='https://unpkg.com/css.gg@2.0.0/icons/css/arrow-down-r.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .dropbtn {
      width: 4rem;
      height: 4rem;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .dropbtn i {
      color: red;
      scale: 1.9;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .content {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: orange;
      width: 100px;
      height: fit-content;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .content::after {
      content: '';
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      transition: all 2s linear;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .content::after {
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .content a {
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <i class="gg-arrow-down-r"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <script src="main.js" defer></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

This works by putting an after pseudo element on .content, it has the height of its 'parent' (.content) which has the same color as the overall background (black in this instance). This pseudo element is anchored at the bottom of .content and it transitions between 100% and 0 height.

With this method you don't have to know how many children .content has or how high they are.

Now, for the more general question of having different animations on .content's children. For this I think you will need JS and another element instead of the pseudo element. Then use IntersectionObserver to see when the element overlaps with a child of .content.

Comment: Thank you for this answer very helpful with one issue but I was not trying to get out of using `JS` trying to figure out how to use `JS` in this instance to my advantage. Currently working on a solution to this but hitting every wall possible. Again Thank a lot for the height solution.

Comment: I'm having extreme trouble replicating your code. I have tried adding new things in to test nothing works. I have then copied the entire solution and tried putting into new fie nothing worked either. Once I hover there is nothing happening. Since the post I've been trying with 0 success..

Comment: I really don't know how to help. Have you copied the entire code, *exactly* as it is, into a new file of type .html and tried to run it on your PC? You need to take out  the link to .css that you ma.y have on your system.

Comment: It's possiibly because your PC has main.css and js on it and these were referenced in the code (as they were there in the question and I had just done a copy of the snippet in its entirety). I have commented them out. Please check there is nothing else that could be on your system that is referenced.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that nothing works, I've not also tried manually entering every line and I understand how things should be but there is nothing to animate from, the initial `.content` never gets `display: block` to actually enable it meaning the pseudo element never there or something along the line. Also got a typo on the `display` I will keep trying tho.

Comment: It's not a typo on the display, it's my (rather lazy) way of 'remembering' what the original code was by having an r in front of it. Have yuu done a copy and paste without changing anything since I removed the main references?

Comment: Yeah, and nothing is working. Tried multiple times.

Comment: Nothing more I can do to help I'm afraid. I assume you have looked at exactly what CSS is being applied in your browser devtools, and experimented with taking certain settings out and so on? Also I assume that you are running the code from a file of type .html on a standard sort of browser (which one, and which OS?)

Comment: Yes I have, I'm using Opera GX, Windows 10. VSCode with Live server and basic .html file yeah.

Comment: Several systems in there I know nothing about. Can you try straightforward Edge or Chrome on the .html file.

Comment: Got it working and the only thing that actually hit me was when you said it was not a typo and I kept adding display: none... AHAHA thats my bad.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your help but the solution you've provided is broken due to the hover not being in the correct space. I have now got my own solution after working on this for a day and I will post the answer once I have removed all the test*** variables and make MINIMAL REPRODUSABLE ANSWER. Thanks.

Comment: Could you say where the hover is and why it's incorrect? [and why does it matter since that is independent of the revealing/hiding?]

Comment: I want the hover to specifically be over the arrow as that is the point of the dropdown menu -> I hover over an arrow / text e.g. contents and I get a dropdown of the available content for that hover. Not hover of empty space underneath the arrow and randomly get things to appear as that's not the intended use for me.

Comment: Currently you have the drop down menu within the same element as the arrow. You can separate them out.